# How do I put basename into a variable?

Tags: file, bash, variables, debian

```
#!/bin/bash
file=debian.deb
test=basename $file .deb
DP="blah/blah/$test/$test.php"
read -p "[$DP]: " DPREPLY
DPREPLY=${DPREPLY:-$DP}
echo "Blah is set to $DPREPLY"
echo $DPREPLY>>testfile
```

So what I'm trying to do is set the variable test from the variable file and use it in the file testfile.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the command substitution `$(...)` mechanism:

```
test=$(basename "$file" .deb)
```

You can also use backquotes, but these are not recommended in modern scripts (mainly because they don't nest as well as the `$(...)` notation).

```
test=`basename "$file" .deb`
```

You need to know about backquotes in order to interpret other people's scripts; you shouldn't be using them in your own.

Note the use of quotes around `"$file"`; this ensures that spaces in filenames are handled correctly.